# Is there a difference in runtime between these two loops, and are there exceptions?

Tags: performance, algorithm, loops, optimization, runtime

Consider the following two loops where N = 10^9 or something large enough to notice inefficiencies with.

```
Loop x = 1 to N
    total += A(x)
    total += B(x)
```

or

```
Loop x = 1 to N
    total += A(x)

Loop x=1 to N
    total += B(x)
```

Where each function takes x, performs some arbitrary arithmetic calculation (e.g. x^2 and 3x^3 or something, doesn't matter), and returns a value.

Are there going to be any differences in overall runtime, and when would this not be the case, if at all?

Comment: Well do the two functions have side-effects where the ordering of execution could affect things? If you've got a specific example in mind, why not try it?

Comment: I can't think of a good example where the ordering of execution would severely affect runtime -- I'll have to think about that a bit. But your response implies that if order doesn't matter (i.e. say they are completely independent functions -- one calculates x^2 and the other calculates x^5, and nothing else), the runtimes should be the same (or at least negligible in difference unless there is a cost to starting a new loop)?

Comment: for above two functions overall difference should be negligible.

Comment: @DoSparKot I suppose my question is starting to become unveiled as potentially ill-formed such that it depends on what is meant by "arbitrary" -- the functions I have in mind don't do anything drastic, just some arbitrary operations that maybe store some values in a cumulative sum variable or something (e.g. say total += A(x) and total += B(x)  )

Comment: @DoubleBass: There *could* be a significant difference based on cache access or something similar - but it would very much depend on the specific case.

Comment: @JonSkeet I updated the OP with a more specific example of what I have in mind.

Comment: @DoubleBass: And what language is this? (Things like inlining rules could make a big difference.)

Comment: If both functions have any common data then altering it will affect overall results; Otherwise operations like finding `X^2` and `3X^3` shouldn't affect much. Of course the overheads(increment, comparison & jumps) of running an extra loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each loop requires four actions:

1. Preparation (once per loop)
2. Checking of the stopping condition (once per iteration)
3. Executing the body of the loop (once per iteration)
4. Adjusting the values used to determine if the iteration should continue (once per iteration)

when you have one loop, you "pay" for items 1, 2 and 4 only once; when you have two loops, you "pay" for everything exactly twice.

Assuming that the order of invoking the two functions is not important, the difference will not be noticeable in most common situations. However, in very uncommon situations of extremely tight loops a single loop will take less CPU resources. In fact, a common technique of [*loop unwinding*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding) relies on reducing the share of per-iteration checks and setup operations in the overall CPU load during the loop by repeating the body several times, and reducing the number of iterations by the corresponding factor.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to think about. One is you're doing twice as many instructions for the loop itself (condition check, incrementing `x`, etc) in the second version. If your functions are really trivial, that could be a major cost.

However, in more realistic situations, cache performance, register sharing, and things like that are going to make a bigger difference. For instance, if both functions need to use a lot of registers, you might find that the second version performs worse than the first because the compiler needs to spill more registers to memory since it's doing it once per loop. Or if `A` and `B` both access the same memory, the second version might be faster than the second because all of `B`'s accesses will be cache hits in the second version but misses in the first version.

All of this is highly program- and platform-specific. If there's some particular program you want to optimize, you need to benchmark it.

Answer (score 1):

The primary difference is that the first one test X against N, N times, while the second one tests X against N, 2N times.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight overhead on the loop itself.

In each Iteration you need to do at least 2 operations, increase the counter, and then compare it to the end value.

So you're doing 2*10^9 more operations.

Answer (score 0):

If both functions used lot's of memory, for example they created some big array, and recursively modified it in each iteration, it could be possible that first loop is slower due to the memory cache or such.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of potential factors to be considered;

1) number of iterations -- does loop setup dominate over the task
2) loop comparison penalty vs. the task complexity

```
for (i=0;i<2;i++) a[i]=b[i];
```

3) general complexity of function
  - with two complex functions one might run out of registers

4) register dependency or are the task serial in nature
  - two independent tasks intermixed vs. result of other loop depends on the first one

5) can the loop be executed completely on a prefetch queue -- no need for cache access
  - mixing in the second tasks may ruin the throughput

6) what kind of cache hit patterns there are